# Getting map in json format coming from a geoserver using wms or wfs

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geoserver, wms

I would like to get a map in json or geojson format from a geoserver. I am already able to work, but in the image format, however this does not serve me, because I need to iterate with the map, putting popups, markers etc.

Here is my code working with image/png, but how work with json or geojson?

```
stComerciaisLayer= L.tileLayer.wms("http://172.25.131.53:8080/geoserver/wms/", {
        layers: 'IGEO:setor_comercial_geo',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true,
        attribution: "Algum texto de teste"
      }).addTo(map);
```

Help me please. Thanks!

Comment: you can add popups to a WMS using GetFeatureInfo requests.

Comment: Have some example or tutorial in jsfiddle? I dont understand, Please, Can you help me?

Comment: see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leaflet

Answer (score 4):

WMS will return an image. You can either modify it on the server, using the layer [style](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/index.html#styling), or you can locally add overlays to it (as a different layer), but you cannot get a list of features using WMS.

To get the individual feature as GeoJSON, you can use [WFS](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/outputformats.html).

Comment: can not return json or geojson by geoserver? I need everything to come from it, I can not put a local .js json file

Comment: @EltonSantos yes you can, but not as wms. Look at wfs (see edited answer)

Comment: Oh God, and so, I have that change all my code for use WFS? This: L.tileLayer.wms("http://172.25.131.53:8080/geoserver/wms/", {
        layers: 'IGEO:setor_comercial_geo',
        format: 'image/png',
        transparent: true
      }).addTo(map); donw work?

Comment: @EltonSantos Yes, they are totally different. Make sure your understand the differences and implications of the two. Styling the layer on the server and rendering as WMS is a very common approach

Comment: Styling I think that's not what I want because I need to interact, popup, colorize a part of the layer by mouse over. In the same way as in this link: http://mapas.fortaleza.ce.gov.br

Comment: I need this: http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/ exactly, but in this case it comes from a local file, in my case I need it to come from a geoserver. Are there any tutorials teaching you how to do this? Something simple, because I do not even know where it's going